# Rundeck states failed execution but all steps are successful

Tags: rundeck

Before we upgrade our Production Rundeck instance we wan't to resolve this issue, any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

We are using Rundeck Community 3.4.8

[image]

Now this does not happen all the time, roughly 10% of deployments that are green will show failed execution:

Exact same job passing:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Do you see any clue in the `service.log` file (at `/var/log/rundeck/service.log` path) at the moment of "failed" execution?

Comment: Hello @MegaDrive68k, thank you for responding. I have created a fresh database and still get the error 10% of the time, I found another failed execution and in the service logs I discovered this:

-----------------------------------------

 [2022-03-17T10:00:01,349] ERROR quartzjobs.ExecutionJob - Execution 355 finishExecution: caught exception: No row with the given identifier exists: [rundeck.Orchestrator#1456]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by removing the orchestrator for the current job, no longer does it say failed execution when all steps are green.